I need to compare 2 csv files with 300000+ text and find matches, then display the matches on the screen. Sheet printing outputs 177232-300000+
I'm reading two CSV files from my computer and filling an arraylist with this data.  Then I compare these two arraylists to find matches.
If the CSV files contain up to 20 lines, then there are no problems finding matches and displaying, but when the CSV file contains more than 300,000 lines, the result is tedious.
The RFM.csv file contains 15000+ lines and displays a complete list of contents, the CSV file contains 300000+ lines and is output after 299000+ lines. But if you output the index separately, then values from 0 to 299000 are output without problems.
The lines in the CSV file are not sorted. The two files contain the full name and date of birth.
Please tell me what is the error?
public class Podft {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        ArrayList<String> listBD = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> listPFM = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

        BufferedReader readerBD = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\d\\Doc\\БД.csv"));
        BufferedReader readerPFM = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\d\\Doc\\РФМ.csv"));

        String lineBD = readerBD.readLine();
        String linePFM = readerPFM.readLine();
        while (lineBD != null) {
            listBD.add(lineBD);
            lineBD = readerBD.readLine();
            }
        while (linePFM != null) {
            listPFM.add(linePFM);
            linePFM = readerPFM.readLine();
        }
for(int i = 0; i < listBD.size(); i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < listPFM.size(); j++){
                if(listBD.get(i).equals(listPFM.get(j))){
                    result.add(listPFM.get(j));
                }
            }
        }
        for (String q : result){
            System.out.println(q);}
    }


Please [edit] your question to include the information, if the lines in the source CSV files are sorted.

[Edit] your question and post sample data from the CSV files. Also when you re   move elements from a List while iterating it, that may cause problems.

I cannot provide test data, as this is personal data.
For example, the data is contained in this format Ivanov Ivan Ivanovich 01.01.1990. The total number is over 300,000.

The sample data doesn't necessarily be actual data. You can make some up. Please see Minimal Reproducible Example.

"Please tell me what is the error?" you first.

If you are not already familiar with a debugger, you should be. However, as far as I can tell, in this case, the "bug" if there is one, appears only after thousands of records have been processed. Have you considered there could be some faulty "records" or corrupt data in one or both of the input files?

The matching code itself works fine with a small amount of lines in files, but it is incorrect with a large amount. A file with 15000+ lines prints correctly from 0 to 15000+, and a file with 300000+ lines prints from 177,000+ to 350000+. At the same time, the data is correct.
I didn't join the Russian Stack Overflow because I don't know how to do it.

I see two major issues in the code you posted.
First, removing items from the iterating List may lead to potential data skipping. The question, in this case is: since the listBD is not returned or printed, why you have to remove items?
Second, a performance issue: for each element of the first list you are scanning each element of the second, obtaining an NxM computational cost. May I suggest to use, for listPFM, a HashSet or at least a LinkedHashSet (if you need to keep the order of the listPFM records, for further analysis) and use the contains method that is based on hash code. Something like this:
for(int i = 0; i < listBD.size(); i++) {
  if(listPFM.contains(listBD.get(i))) {
    result.add(listBD.get(i));
  }
}

This should be faster.

I tried to use the removal of elements out of desperation, as I have been suffering for several weeks. But when I tried it with him, I got an error. Therefore, it has now been deleted.
C HashSet is a very good idea, thank you. But they still don't find a match.
But when I print listBD, it outputs information to me from the index 177232, not from 0. And I can't understand why, and I think that's why I'm not being tested.
I have an excel file in one column, full name in the other, date of birth, I convert the excel file to csv and read it with an entry in the arraylist.

And on listPFM.get(j), idea swears

@ДмитрийСергеевич sorry for listPFM.get(j), i fixed the code, I wrote here on the fly and kept the old reference. Since they're equals, it's the same.

@ДмитрийСергеевич Are you sure the formats of the lines are the same? Using the equals method on strings, you may have a mismatch also for blank spaces, even if the data seems to be the same.

LinkedHashSet doesn't have a get() method and that's why Idea swears.
I tried using contains, but I also can't find the same values.
The format of the rows in my excel is the same. When I print a listPFM sheet, the index output starts from 0 to 15000+. And when I output listbb, the index output starts from 277232 to 350000+, and should be from 0 to 350000+. And I think this is the problem, because indexes 0=0 and 0=277232 are compared.

Keep listBD as a List, and you'll have the get(i) method. As I wrote before, I made a mistake in the code, now I have fixed it. For the indexes, I can just suggest to debug and check step by step what is actually loaded in the collections.

Now I use these sheets. Right?
List listBD = new ArrayList<>(); LinkedHashSet listPFM = new LinkedHashSet<>(); ArrayList result = new ArrayList<>();
I record the read data from the file in them and after
for(int i = 0; i < listBD.size(); i++) {
if(listPFM.contains(listBD.get(i))) {
result.add(listBD.get(i));
}
}
I look for matches in them and deduce them. so?

Yes, this is what I meant.

I did so, but I have the result:
Process finished with exit code 0.
Although there are 5 matches in the sheets, this is for sure.
Please tell me how to debug indexes. I believe that the problem is with them and I need to upload them correctly.
